# Attribute Join creates headers but cells remain empty in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I'm trying to carry out an attribute join using one CSV and shapefile using the "LSOA11CD" fields as pictured below

[image: shapefile attribute table]

[image: csv file]

The join validates in ArcGIS Desktop, however I get the following error message when I try to join the two tables.

[image: error message]

The CSV contains significantly more entries than the shapefile field, however identical entries are present in each of the tables.

Comment: Could you please describe in detail the exact process you used to create the join?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: There aren't any matches shown on this attribute in your example screen shots, perhaps they just don't show here. Did you sort the tables and check that there are matches?